# Magento - Extending a community module

Tags: magento

I want to extend a community module's Mindstretch_BetterAddress_Model_Sales class which extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address to My_Sales_Model_Quote_Address 
below is my xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <My_Sales>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </My_Sales>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <models>
      <betteraddress>
          <rewrite>
              <sales>My_Sales_Model_Quote_Address</sales>
          </rewrite>
      </betteraddress>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

My module's config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <My_Sales>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
  <depends>
   <Mage_Sales/>
   <Mindstretch_BetterAddress/>
  </depends>
    </My_Sales>
  </modules>
</config>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi try this : <models>
      <sales>
          <rewrite>
              <quote_address>My_Sales_Model_Quote_Address</quote_address>
          </rewrite>
      </sales>
    </models>

Comment: what is happening right now? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm trying to overwrite a method, but it's not working.

Comment: @dagfr
Your suggestion worked. I don't get why though.
I thought I had to set the path to the community module in the config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <models> 
     <sales> 
         <rewrite> 
              <quote_address>My_Sales_Model_Quote_Address</quote_address> 
         </rewrite> 
     </sales> 
 </models>
```

Because it's this model you rewrite originally, the `depends` instruction will make your file works first before the Mindstretch_BetterAddress file.